# Auto expand QTreeView Items

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qtreeview

I am trying to change QTreeView with a auto update and I am able to set path with this code

`tree->setCurrentIndex(fsModel->index(QDir::currentPath())); // or any path`## Heading ## Got from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5242161/how-to-select-a-file-in-qtreeview-for-a-qfilesystemmodel-by-path/10747361#10747361)

But my question is how I can expand once CurrentIndex changed for a folder ?

Comment: Again ignore it please tree->setExpanded(fsModel->index(QDir::currentPath())); will do that.

Comment: In this case I think it's ok if you answer your own question and accept your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Again ignore it please tree->setExpanded(fsModel->index(QDir::currentPath())); will do that.